# Spring does not receive all Cookies

Tags: spring, cookies

I'm trying to handle some cookies with Spring.

For that I'm easily geting them like this: `request.getCookies();`

Now I noticed that Spring shows me only 6 of 10 cookies. In Firefox I see way more.

If I run `theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');` in the browser console, I get only 5 cookies, but the one I'm looking for does contain in the list but not in the list from Spring.

Comment: It will receive all cookies that are allowed on that URL. So if there are more cookies in your browser it might be that some are for other (sub) URLS for the website.

Comment: I thought about that. But firefox shows me the same url and "/" as path.

Comment: One secure the other isn't. There must be a reason that the server doesn't see them. Please add the needed information to your question.

Comment: I found the problem ... the missing cookie in Spring contained a comma which is not allowed.